# Histoire du français

Tags: histoire, ressources

Je suis tombé sur une vidéo ["How the English language developed"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyI-Tex_k14) aujourd'hui.

Je voulais savoir s'il existait soit une vidéo du même genre concernant l'histoire de la langue française, ou une page web de référence sur l'origine et l'histoire de la langue.

Comment: La page de [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais) est déjà un bon début.

Comment: En effet, mais disons que c'est beaucoup moins "grand public" que cette vidéo sur l'histoire anglaise :(

Comment: Chez moi, le lien ne marche pas, par vidéo retirée. De l'avantage de décrire ce qui se cache derrière les liens : « du genre », qu'est-ce à dire ?

Comment: J'ai mis à jour le lien, merci Nikana Reklawyks

Comment: Admirable. Cela dit, la meta-critique tient toujours : tant que ça n'est pas hébergé sur SE, ça peut toujours [remourir](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/4432/1514), et une petite description serait la bienvenue. Éditeurs, à vous…

Answer (score 3):

- [C'est pas sorcier : Les sorciers jouent sur les mots](http://c-est-pas-sorcier.france3.fr/?page=emission&id_article=314) : Histoire de la langue française et des jeux de mots ; un peu plus sérieux, et davantage pour les enfants.

Comment: (Moi je n'arrive pas à la visualiser facilement, et je n'insiste pas.) C'est sûrement plus complet, et surtout, clair, mais aussi plus long. Le format youtube-en-parlant-vite rentre sûrement mieux dans l'*attention span* moderne de base. (Et pour être pragmatique, c'est pour ça que j'ai regardé l'original alors que là, je n'insiste pas.)