# Comment dériver les termes manquants ?

Tags: néologismes

- *Refaire X* : *re-X**. Très bien, je [reposterai](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/quel-est-lequivalent-de-emphasis-mine-pour-une-citation?rq=1#comment8005_1683).
- *Défaire X* : *dé-X*. Soit, « [le préfixe *dé-* est générateur](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1333/1514) », [*désépinons*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1354/1514), [*désaiguillonnons*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1355/1514), et [*dépinglons*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2893/1514), puisque Joubarc ne veut pas que l'on [*dépine*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1354/1514).

*Wait, what ?* En fait, c'est plus souvent compliqué que simple, semble-t-il :

- *Ceux qui défient* : *défiants*¹ ? *défieurs* ? *Challenger* est un verbe, en québecois, mais l'emploi de son participe présent en français risque de s'attirer moult froncement de sourcils.
- *Le fait d'implorer* : *implorement* ? [*imploration*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2108/1514) ? *impleur* ?
- *Celui qui est à l'origine de quelque chose* : l'*originateur* ? l'*origine* ? l'[*originataire*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/quel-est-lequivalent-de-emphasis-mine-pour-une-citation?rq=1#comment8006_1689) ? (outre l'*instigateur*, qui ne peut pas toujours s'appliquer, et le *coupable*, trop facile).

**Y a-t-il une pratique établie pour ces cas-là ?**

L'heureux élu de notre esthétique personnelle a-t-il droit de *prévalence* (*prévaluation*, *prévaleur*) sur une éventuelle famille du radical ? On remarquera
[`prévaloir:valoir::prévaleur:valeur`](http://cental.fltr.ucl.ac.be/~taln2006/index.php?lang=fr&page=18), mais est-ce une justification valable contre l'euphonie qui me fait utiliser une autre racine ?

Écorchez-les tous, et la langue reconnaîtra les siens ?

¹ Le sens en a beaucoup évolué, que je sache.

Comment: Question extrêmement intéressante également à tous ceux qui, comme moi, ont l'ambition d'essayer d'automatiser ce genre de production de termes... Merci beaucoup de l'avoir posée.

Comment: C'est une question pour les journalistes (qui ont fait machine arrière avec le déjà daté _reculade_) ou bien pour les politiques (_bravitude_, _abracadabrantesque_, etc.)

Comment: Mais, heu... quelle est la question ?? S'il s'agit de savoir si la langue reconnaîtra les siens après qu'on ait écorché tout le monde, la réponse est PEUT-ÊTRE.

Comment: (@Istao : La question est en gras.)

Comment: [Discussion sur Méta](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/392/reconnaissez-que-cette-question-est-maladive)

Comment: [Encore un exemple](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/un-nom-pour-laction-de-completer-une-action).

Comment: Une suggestion de reformulation : « comment créer le mot au croisement d'une nature (lexicale) et d'un concept (sémantique), quand celui-ci n'existe pas (encore) ? » Avec l'interrogation annexe « la création est-elle légitime ? », que je présuppose dans la question (en plus d'y adhérer avec peu de retenue).

Comment: J'avais raté ce commentaire, c'est une très bonne suggestion ça donne du sens à la question. Encore faudrait-il expliciter un peu quels sont les divers concepts sémantiques qui sont applicables à de nombreux cas.

Comment: Un peu tard certes, mais suite à la discussion sur Méta, je clos la question. Vu la remarque de @StéphaneGimenez, elle peut peut-être être clarifiée, auquel cas elle pourra bien sûr être rouverte.

Answer (score 2):

Pas de pratique connue ni de règles strictes. Les néologismes se forment d'eux-mêmes au feeling de la personne qui les invente. Par exemple, pourquoi "*bravitude*" et pas "*bravité*" ?

De même il y a des cas où le sens d'un mot ne peut être trouvé à partir de son radical, ses préfixes et ses suffixes. Un célèbre humoriste français avait d'ailleurs fait un sketch sur le sujet (avec de mémoire "*dégueuler*" qui ne signifie pas "*dé-gueuler*" - contraire de "*gueuler*" - mais "*vomir*").

Comment: Bon. Si c'est la triste vérité, alors les prescriptivistes français me déçoivent :P