# Comment dire « de façon seyante » en un seul mot ?

Tags: demande-de-mot, synonymes

Je cherche [un seul mot](http://www.maphilo.net/citations.php?cit=1867),  pour dire ***[seyament](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4432)***, *de façon appropriée*, *comme il faut*.

Typiquement, il manque de l'information à un des interlocuteurs pour préciser ce qu'est cette bonne façon, mais l'information est connue de l'autre interlocuteur, ou le sera dans le futur.

Par exemple :

> Pour jouer cette chanson, suivant l'effet que tu veux donner, tu devras jouer tels et tels accords sur ta guitare *adéquatement* accordée (accordée **de la bonne façon par rapport à l'effet désiré**).
>
> Quand tout sera terminé, selon la date et où il se trouve, contacte Paul *par le moyen idoine* et dis lui de passer (utilise le moyen de communication le plus adapté par rapport à sa localisation, la date et l'heure).

Quel mot unique pourrait remplacer "*de la bonne façon par rapport à l'effet désiré*", et "*par le moyen idoine*" ?

Autres reformulations et suggestions plus ou moins insatisfaisantes :

> **accordingly**
> seyant, adéquatement,
> convenablement, proprement, correspondamment,
> comme de juste, comme il se doit
> de la bonne façon, en conséquence, de façon adaptée
> *appropriately*, *correspondingly*, *suitably*

Des idées ?

Comment: À sa plus simple expression, _bien/bon_ fonctionne, mais ce n'est pas le même mot. Cependant ça illustre que dans le 2e exemple c'est bien _idoine_ qui est le mot qu'on tente de remplacer... c'est un adjectif ça et pas un adverbe. Pour que l'adverbe joue le rôle de l'adjectif, il doit être enrobé pour ainsi dire ; avec une préposition et un participe passé par exemple... Autrement ça prend un mot qui peut être adverbe et adjectf à la fois ? Merci.

Comment: En anglais, après « appropriately», mon 2eme choix serait «correspondingly» comme adverbe pour la guitare et «corresponding» comme adjectif pour le moyen de contacte correspondant, mais, hélas,  «correspondantement» n’a pas l’air d’être un mot (et «proportionnellement» ne me dit rien dans ce contexte d’une guitare en accordage correspondant) donc tout ça pour dire pas grand-chose! Sorry!

Comment: Survenant et @PapaPoule, vous avez bien compris la question et vos remarques sont justes. [*Correspondamment*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/CORRESPONDAMMENT) pourrait faire l'affaire. Est-ce que c'est un mot ? :D

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks -- Correspondamment (bien qu'accepté du bout des lèvres depuis 2007) fleure le pur anglicisme selon mon correcteur orthographique, car abandonné par la francophonie depuis belle lurette, http://atilf.atilf.fr/academie9.htm l'ignore. S'il peut caler le nombre de pied d'un vers, sa lourdeur manque totalement de poésie... à moins d'en trouver dans le langage administratif. -- Parmi les synonymes de *seyant* : *http://www.synonymo.fr/synonyme/seyant* il y a un bon nombre que vous pourrez transformer en adverbe, retrouver le nom d'origine ou utiliser tel quel.

Comment: Another relevant English adverb to add to the two you already mention would be “accordingly,” which could lead to the somewhat relevant abbreviated two-word French adverb “d’autant.” To enter reluctantly into the discussion of whether using “dépendamment” is crucial to [the understanding of] your question, I would note that, based on my interpretation of the meaning of your 2 examples, I would not use the corresponding English adverb “dependently” but instead “depending on” which, as mentioned below, would lead to “selon” or ”suivant,” neither of which would, imo, change your good question.

Comment: @PapaPoule Effectivement, *accordingly** est exactement ce que je cherche, on pourrait changer le titre en "comment traduire accordingly ?". "D'autant"... convient dans certains contextes (quand "de la bonne façon" correspond à "dans des quantités égales"), mais pas dans d'autres (*"Vu que tu joues à un concert country/folk, accorde ta guitare d'autant"). Merci pour l'avis supplémentaire sur "dépendamment".

Comment: @cl-r "Depuis belle lurette" : apparemment, l'occurence principale est dans [un dictionnaire d'ancien français](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/CORRESPONDAMMENT). Ton idée suggère "**convenablement**", "*séamment", et "bien", qui sont des bonnes idées.

Comment: « tel et tel accords » est toujours incorrect, *tel* doit s'accorder avec *accords*.

Comment: @jlliagre Effectivement. J'ai appris [quelque chose](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1588), et [ce n'est pas](http://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=tel) sur fr.SE.

Comment: Il suffisait pourtant de bien lire ma réponse, je l'avais mis en gras.

Answer (score 1):

Ces deux phrases peuvent difficilement utiliser le même mot. Une manière (forme) et un moyen (fond) [sont certes liés mais ne sont pas interchangeables](http://latlntic.unige.ch/grammaticalite/?page_id=1596).

Voici comment je les tournerais :

> Pour jouer cette chanson, **suivant** l'effet que tu veux donner, tu devras jouer **tels et tels** accords sur ta guitare accordée **en conséquence** / **de manière appropriée**.
>
> Quand tout sera terminé, **quelle que soit l'heure et où qu'il se trouve**, contacte Paul par le moyen **approprié** / **le mieux indiqué** / **le plus adapté** et **dis-lui** de passer.

Note: Dépendamment existe en français mais, contrairement à indépendamment, est d'une part extrêmement rare et d'autre part inutilisable ici.

Comment: @cl-r Remplacer « dépendamment » par « indépendamment » est un contresens, « mettre en valeur » ne me semble non plus pas très fidèle au sens décrit de la question.

Comment: Pour jouer cette chanson, *selon* l'effet que tu veux donner, tu devras jouer tels et tels accords *adaptés à* la guitare - *Seyant* : mettre en valeur, montrer à son avantage, valoriser la présentation. S'utilise souvent pour un vêtement, une coiffure, un bijou qui met en valeur une personne, mais pas pour valoriser un objet : pour ma part, je ne saurais dire que cela rend une guitare seyante, alors que cette dernière peut rendre une personne seyante.

Comment: Embarqué par *dépendamment* j'avais fait une lecture superficielle :( ! .

Comment: @cl-r Pourquoi pas pour *selon* mais c'est ici un synonyme de *suivant*.

Comment: Bien sûr, la façon dont tu tournes les phrases est bien plus idiomatique, mais ce n'est pas la question que je pose. Je cherche un mot, et j'indique deux contextes artificiels dans lesquels ce mot pourrait s'employer. Les contextes sont volontairement les plus distincts possibles, et les phrases sont contraintes. *Dépendamment* est une partie cruciale de l'idée que je cherche à exprimer, la "bonne façon" dépend de paramètres. *Adapté* représente bien ce que je veux dire.

Comment: Le problème est pas tant que que ces phrases ne sont pas idiomatiques mais surtout qu'elles sont ambiguës et difficilement compréhensibles. L'utilisation insistante du mot « dépendamment » qui n'est jamais utilisé en français prête à confusion. Le sens de la subordonnée relative à la guitare n'est pas clair du tout. Le mieux serait de fournir une version anglaise ou en toute autre langue maternelle de ces phrases. De plus, comme déjà indiqué @SurvenantLazurite dans son commentaire, il est difficile de trouver un mot adéquat à la fois adjectif et adverbe.

Comment: Oh, mille excuses, je n'avais pas compris ça. Au québec c'est employé couramment, donc c'est utilisable ici, mais par contre ils admettent que ça n'est pas un vrai mot. Je vais de ce pas rendre la question compréhensible. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

*ad hoc* répond à ce sens et peut être utilisé comme adjectif ou adverbe:

*Répondez ad hoc.* (Littré) - trouvé sur [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ad%20hoc)

*Une méthode ad hoc.*

Hélas, ce n'est pas un mot unique.

De manière équivalente, on peut utiliser:

- convenable, convenablement;
- idoine (pas d'adverbe);
- adéquat (pas d'adverbe);
- aproprié (pas d'adverbe);
- précis, précisément.

Comment: Tu peux donner un exemple d'utilisation d'*ad hoc* comme adverbe ? J'ai du mal à construire "*contacte Paul* ad hoc" convenablement. Je m'étonne de ne pas l'avoir mentionné dans les suggestions, mais oui, j'y ai pensé (et ça va, c'est 5 lettres, c'est un mot ^^ ce que je veux éviter, c'est la périphrase "de la façon la plus appropriée").

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks , j'ai complété la réponse avec l'exemple pour "ad hoc".

Answer (score 0):

Ces deux situations correspondent à deux idées distinctes en français. Il n'y a pas de mot qui les recouvre les deux.

- Dans la première phrase tu veux dire "de manière adéquate, appropriée..."
- Dans la seconde tu veux dire "avec un moyen adéquat, approprié..."

Ce sont deux sens différents, et il n'y a pas de raison qu'un même mot les recouvre.

Comment: *Moyen* et *manière* sont synonymes. Pourquoi les sens seraient différents ?

Comment: Moyen et manière ne sont pas vraiment synonymes, il y a parfois un recouvrement des sens mais ces deux mots ne sont pas interchangeables. Selon le Tlfi, **Moyen** est ce qui permet d'atteindre un but, **manière** décrit la forme particulière que revêt un processus, une méthode ou un état. Comparer par exemple « **Je n'ai pas les moyens d'acheter cette bague mais je ne sait pas de quelle manière le faire comprendre à  ma fiancée** » avec l'improbable « ***Je n'ai pas les manières d'acheter cette bague mais je ne sais pas par quel moyen le faire comprendre à ma fiancée.** »

Comment: Ton exemple est... moyen. Tu utilises l'expression *avoir les moyens* (= *avoir de l'argent*) pour montrer qu'on ne peut pas remplacer *moyen* par *manière*. Alors que ce serait plutôt *je n'ai aucun moyen d'obtenir cette bague* - que ce soit l'acheter, la voler, me la faire céder, etc. Et dans ce cas, *je n'ai aucune manière d'obtenir cette bague* fonctionne bien.

Comment: Les *moyens* c'est le potentiel, ce que tu peux faire, ou les fonds que tu peux lever. La *manière* c'est comment tu fais quelque chose. Tu peux avoir la possibilité, les moyens, de faire quelque chose, mais la manière dont tu le fais ne sera pas définie tant que tu ne l'auras pas fait.

Comment: Par exemple, un outil est un moyen, mais pas une manière. Un ami qui t'aide est un moyen et pas une manière, un patron de construction est un moyen et peut ensuite devenir la manière, le geste que tu fais pour planter un clou est la manière, et pas un moyen.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Mon exemple est peut-être moyen mais il n'est sûrement pas manière ;-)  *Je n'ai aucune manière d'obtenir cette bague* n'est pas idiomatique. « De quel manière » et « par quel moyen » ne signifient pas la même chose, le premier s'applique à la forme, le second au fond. PS: ne pas oublier le @ suivi du nom/pseudo du destinataire du commentaire si différent de l'auteur de la question ou de la réponse commentée.